# How to compare various types(integer,string,boolean...) values saved as string/varchar using creteria restrictions?

Tags: hibernate, criteria, restriction

So i'm currently saving various field types as string( in hbm files)/varchar values in the DB. These types range from dates, booleans, integers, strings,etc...

So using this to make queries:

```
            Integer value=12;
            String value="hello";
            Calendar value= Calendar.getInstance();
            Boolean value=Boolean.TRUE;
            fieldCriteria=Restrictions.gt(fieldInstValue, valor);
```

where fieldInstValue is the field column and value the value im searching in.
What happens if i pass different types as value, like an Integer, Boolean or a calendar type as the value param, considering everything is saved in the DB as a string/varchar, will it compare the integer as really int values? what about booleans or calendar/date java types?will it attempt to convert the string value first to these types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do that, you will see

```
ClassCastException.
```

Hibernate does not try to convert anything, You will have to do it your self.

For Interger, Boolean you can just do `String.valueOf()`.

For dates, You have to use date formatter(`SimpleDateFormat`) to format the date in same way which is stored in db and then you can use in the criteria.

I don't know why are you storing everything as String, If you do this, Only thing work correctly is equals, rest i.e less than, greater than, it will just lexicological compare strings. ie `"A" < "B" = True`.

Here's an example

```
SELECT * FROM `some_table` WHERE valor < "2";
```

This will return all the records which starts with value less than 2. which would include "12", "1222222". It is not comparing integer it just compares the `String`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if i use String.valueOf(valor) for integer value, then how will it compare them, like valor>2, will it compare them as integers?

Comment: How can it do that if you have stored `valor` as varchar? It will not show any error but the result will be incorrect.

Comment: Yep, seems i have a problem with this solution. Thanks.

Comment: Still is there any solution where i can let the values being stored as string. Can i do anything to convert them myself?

Comment: You can do something like `SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE CAST(valor AS UNSIGNED) < CAST("2" AS UNSIGNED);` in native sql. I don't think hibernate will let you do that.

Comment: same way for dates you can use mysql `DATE()` function.

Comment: Dont you mean:
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE CAST(fieldInstValue AS UNSIGNED) < CAST(valor AS UNSIGNED);

Comment: so I got it: Hibernate will not try to cast/parse String to Integer, etc. We do it. Thx.